# How to get updated variables in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am working with C++ and opengl using glfw library.
I wrote a program that moves a model using arrows key in xy plane using GLFW_GETKEY
it looks little bit like this-

```
    void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

    float x = -3.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;

    int main()
    {
           //some rendering code....
.
.
.
        Shader gun("gun.vs", "gun.fs");
            gun.use();
        gun.setMat4("projection", projection);
        gun.setMat4("view", view);

           //transformation
        transform = glm::translate(scale, glm::vec3(x, y, 1.0f));
        gun.setMat4("model", transform);
    }
    void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
    {
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_UP) == GLFW_PRESS)
            y += 0.1;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_DOWN) == GLFW_PRESS)
            y += -0.1;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_LEFT) == GLFW_PRESS)
            x += -0.1;
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_RIGHT) == GLFW_PRESS)
            x += 0.1;
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
        std::cout << y << std::endl;

    }
```

values of x any y updates in console when cout is used inside processInput funtion but not in main loop.

Anybody have explanation for this thing.

Comment: Without knowing where these declarations are relative to the event handling code, I'm guessing you declared them inside the loop (ie you get fresh variables every time) instead of outside the loop.

Comment: _"the value don't update"_ - does that mean the same values as before are printed?

Comment: yes it prints -3.0 and 0.0

Comment: Then the model probably depends on different variables with the same names.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I can imagine many variants of code that don't do what you expect, but it is impossible to know what is the problem in your code unless you show it

Comment: I have solved my problem but I need a explanation for this. you can check the updated question.

Comment: If the code is exactly like in the question, it would work. (at least it does if I copy your code and fill in the missing pieces as I expect them to be). Are you sure that you use the same x,y variables in main and processInput? Are you sure there are no local variables with the same name in any of this methods? Please also show your main-loop since as of now your main method would never use x,y after the first time.

Comment: Yes I don't have any.

Comment: 100% you had another x,y variables in the main scope. It's always better to don't use common variables name when you use them as a global variable